# ImageMapster text overlay

Tags: text, canvas, dictionary, overlay, imagemapster

How to achieve text overlay in ImageMapster?
ImageMapster seems to be a very popular plugin and I am doing research in order to decide whether to use it in my project. In the application that I am going to develop, percentage numbers need to be shown on selected area on the maps. Since, ImageMapster is not supporting this feature, I was wondering how others have done it? What are workarounds? 
I read in forums that few others too are struggling with writing text on selected area.
Since it uses canvas, we could create elements dynamically and show on the selected area, could we? I am not sure whether canvas coordinates and map coordinates are same though.

Any pointers in this text overlay problem would be great. So, that I can make decision about ImageMapster :)

Comment: Any solution yet? I'm also looking to do the same, and while I know I could write the code to do it myself, it sure would be nice to find this baked-in...